# Search from list in React Native

Tags: list, react-native, search

I just wanna know how can I make search function in react native. I have a very big list of text(in local js file) and also Text input space. I want to make possible when users type something they can find what they looking for from list below. Here is my code and screenshot of App. I'm new in programming so please use easy terms =) [app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0oaM.png)

[project datebase sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEyqZ.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import {DATA} from "../Data/AbrData";


const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const SearchScreen = ({navigator}) => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
      
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
            style={{
                height: 50,
                borderColor: '#919191',
                borderWidth: 1,
                margin: 10,
                paddingLeft: 15,
                borderRadius:10
                    
            }}
            placeholder="Axtaris..."
            
        />
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
    marginBottom:75,
    

  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#ededed',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

export default SearchScreen;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really Fast this is what I came up with.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const DATA = [{title: 'lorumn ispum'}, {title: 'lorumn ispum'}];
  const [searchText, onChangeSearch] = useState('');
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = DATA.filter(item =>
      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()),
    );
    if (searchText === '') {
      return setFilteredData(DATA);
    }

    setFilteredData(filtered);
  }, [searchText]);

  const Item = ({title}) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({item}) => <Item title={item.title} />;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          height: 50,
          borderColor: '#919191',
          borderWidth: 1,
          margin: 10,
          paddingLeft: 15,
          borderRadius: 10,
        }}
        onChangeText={newText => onChangeSearch(newText)}
        placeholder="Axtaris..."
      />
      <FlatList
        data={filteredData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
    marginBottom: 75,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#ededed',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

export default App;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest watching this video! I learned how to simply filter a list from this video. Its plain js but the idea is the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlP5WIxVirU&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

If you look at the repo of that video it boils down to the following:

```
searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  users.forEach(user => {
    const isVisible =
      user.name.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      user.email.toLowerCase().includes(value)
    user.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
  })
})
```

Everytime the input changes (someone type something in the search field), the event listener is fired and converts the fields to lower case and compares it to the value your looking for. If the text contains the value it unhides it from the list. it does this for every entry in your dataset and thus filters the dataset to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend. This is exactly what I want, but beacuse of my very low knowledge I cant use this information in my code. But anyway thanks for your respond

Comment: No problem. I suggest you add the dataset you are using in your question so someone can better help you write the code and the solution. I could but you don't have enough info.

Comment: ok I added a database sample. I just need code example that I can paste in my code. Cause I've watched too many videos they are all the same, and when I do exactly how the saying it's not working. But I will not give it up =)

Comment: @AliValiyev I made a new answer please take a look.